# Printing pi with large precision using GMP

Tags: c++, precision, gmp

Right now I have this little code that I want to print pi to x decimals:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpf_set_default_prec(1000);
    mpf_t pi;
    mpf_init(pi); 
    mpf_set_d(pi, atan(1)*4);
    cout << pi << endl;

}
```

I just sat default_prec to 1000 as I thought that would give me plenty of decimals, but no matter what I set it to, I only get 5. How can I print more?

Comment: `#include <iomanip>`, `std::setprecision(1000)`, `std::fixed`...

Comment: Does it not still use `atan` for `float` (or `double`) in this case - you need to use the mpf_atan (if there is such a thing - otherwise, google for "ways to calculate digits in pi".

Comment: @H2CO3: Don't think that helps. The problem is that the calculation is doing `float atan`, and then storing the result in a GMP number, which won't make it more precise.

Comment: @MatsPetersson (+1 That's what I was thinking about, but I wasn't sure... surely there's no way a `double` can store 1000 significant digits...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I tried this first, but then it printed the wrong numbers! After about decimal number 20, I get the wrong numbers. I would expect this in a double, but not in a GMP float.

Comment: The GMP homepage recommends using MPFR instead if you need bigfloats.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `atan(1)*4` will only be evaluated with single (or double) precision, since this part of the code has nothing to do with gmp and will use the standard c++ types. The program will evaluate atan(1)*4 first and then convert the result into an mpf_t.
On the GMP homepage there is a page on how to calculate [Pi with many digits](http://gmplib.org/pi-with-gmp.html%20%5BPi%20with%20GMP%5D).

Comment: That makes sense, but how should I do it then? Do I have to create an algorithm that will compute pi?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I don't know a simple way like using atan(mpf). There are various algorithms to compute pi. Many can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pi_algorithms).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks, will download mpfr now :)

Comment: Right. I forgot about the [MPFR library](http://www.mpfr.org/), which provides more functions than GMP...